# Passing data from a tab bar view to a screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to pass data from a tab bar to the screens in flutter . Is this possible ? If yes, How to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is you can use same controller for different pages the data is saved in controllers and you can use them in different classes and screens.